# PyQT change the position in the GridLayout for inner QVBoxLayout

Tags: python-3.x, position, pyqt5

I'm working with PyQT and I have very simple structure Grid layout and inner BoxLayout into this grid (code generated below by QtDesigner. Sorry about it's ugly view)

In short here is my BoxLayer

```
self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.buttonsLayer, 2, 0, 1, 2)
```

and later I've tried to change it's position by executing this instruction (I want to move this layout to the 3 row of the GridLayout)

```
self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.buttonsLayer, 3, 0, 1, 2)
```

but I've got an error ***QLayout::addChildLayout: layout "buttonsLayer" already has a parent***

At start I had buttons right in the Grid Layout but later I've decided to push them into some container and move only this container instead moving of 2 objects.  But..strange, for the single button this trick was working but for the Layout it doesn't work.

Maybe someone has some idea why it doesn't work and how can I change the position for the BoxLayer?  Thanks for any info!

```
 MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(608, 173)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.addFileBtn_0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.addFileBtn_0.setObjectName("addFileBtn_0")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.addFileBtn_0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.lineEditFile_0 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEditFile_0.setText("")
    self.lineEditFile_0.setObjectName("lineEditFile_0")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEditFile_0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.addFileBtn_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.addFileBtn_1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.addFileBtn_1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.addFileBtn_1.setObjectName("addFileBtn_1")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.addFileBtn_1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.lineEditFile_1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEditFile_1.setObjectName("lineEditFile_1")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEditFile_1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    self.buttonsLayer = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self.buttonsLayer.setObjectName("buttonsLayer")
    self.addFileGroupBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.addFileGroupBtn.setObjectName("addFileGroupBtn")
    self.buttonsLayer.addWidget(self.addFileGroupBtn)
    self.saveConfigBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.saveConfigBtn.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.saveConfigBtn.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.saveConfigBtn.setObjectName("saveConfigBtn")
    self.buttonsLayer.addWidget(self.saveConfigBtn)
    self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.buttonsLayer, 2, 0, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 10-20 different tries to achieve what I want and native QT documentation invesigation I've found finally a possible solution. I'm not sure that it's an ideal way but it works. If you have some better solution - please let me know! I'll be appropriated.

Here is the solution

```
#  remove this item(it's  aLayout so we can't use removeWidget) from GridLayout
self.gridLayout.removeItem(self.buttonsLayer)

# now we can insert it into some new place. Voalia =)
self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.buttonsLayer, self.fieldGroupCounter + 1, 0, 1, 2)
```

Hope it helps someone! Kind regards.